# Transaction only works once with simultaneous calls

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

We are using the code below in an application to execute a write to the database. However, multiple clients may be writing at the same time so we used a `Transaction` as this is supposed to run again if the data is modified by another `Transaction` during execution.
Something seemed to go wrong though: When seperate clients (two different mobile devices) are running the code below ± simultaneously, only one of them seems to update the value in the database.

What could be the cause of this and how can we prevent this in the future?

```
  static Future< bool > voteOnUser(GroupData groupData, String voteeID) async {

    await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
      DocumentReference groupRef = Firestore.instance
                                    .collection("groups")
                                    .document( groupData.getGroupCode() );

      DocumentSnapshot ds = await transaction.get( groupRef );

      /// Initialize lists
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> dbData = ds.data['newVotes'];
      Map<String, int> convertedData = new Map<String, int>();

      /// Loop the database Map and add the values to the data Map
      /// All data is assumed to exist and definitely be of the desired types
      dbData.forEach( (key, value) {
        convertedData[key.toString()] = value;
      } );

      if (convertedData.containsKey( voteeID ))
        convertedData[voteeID] += 1;
      else convertedData[voteeID] = 1;

      Map<String, dynamic> incremented = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      incremented['newVotes'] = convertedData;

      await transaction.update(groupRef, incremented);

    });

    return true;

  }
```

**Edit**: The purpose of this code is to vote on a user that is located in a map within a document. Several clients may vote at the same time and each vote should increment the value of one element in the map by one.
When two clients vote at the same time on for example the user with ID 'joe' who had no votes before, the expected result is that joe would have two votes. However, when testing simultaneous voting, we observed that only one vote was added to the database instead of the desired two votes.

**Edit 2**: At first, the document exists and contains an empty map `newVotes`. We were testing with two different mobile devices and casted a vote at ± the same point in time. Almost instantly, the document was updated and a user ID was added to the previously empty map with one vote while we expected two votes to be mapped to that key.

**Edit 3**: First, a document is created with the following fields: newVotes (map) to map a number of votes to a unique user id, totalVotes (map) to keep track of the total votes and members (List) which is a list of all user id's in that group. newVotes And totalVotes are empty at this point and members contains a few IDs (in this case, two unique Google IDs)
Once this document exists, clients can vote with the given code. In my case we both voted on the same google user ID (say: "ID1")  and expected the map newVotes to contain one element: {"ID1": 2}. However, we both voted at the same time (no errors were thrown) and the newVotes field contained {"ID1":1}.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain exactly what you're observing that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope I made my problem clear this time.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What exactly does the document contain before the code is executed?  What does it contain afterward?  How is that different than the expected contents?

Comment: I added another edit, that should clarify things a bit.

Comment: 1) are you locking that entity fo reading expliclity? 2) Optimistic lockig (version controll) is what you are looking for.

Comment: So there is code that writes to the document outside of the confines of this transaction?  Care to share all the code that deals with this document?

Comment: @Antoniossss 1) I am not, but that shouldn't be required if I understood the documentation correctly. 2) Thank you, I'll take a look.

Comment: @DougStevenson Only the given code is modifying the document but that same code can be executed simultaneously from different devices.

Comment: @DieterNuytemans which documentation? Link plz.

Comment: This one: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: I'm at a loss because I still don't have a picture of the exact contents of the document before and after execution.  It would help if you could edit the question to spell out exactly the sequence of events with exact data, and how the results don't match what you expect.  Have you tried debug logging to make sure everything is exactly as it's supposed to be before, during and after?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will do as you ask. I have not tried that yet, and will look into that as well.

Comment: Took me a while as I'm on mobile now but I added a third edit.

Answer (score 0):

`Transactions` does not guarantee protection from modification of the same entity concurently - unless SERIALIZED (or "Read for update locking"). It guarantees that every operations in transaction will be applied at once upon `commit` or discarded if tx is `rolled back`

To guarantee that there are no conflicts either:

1. Synchronize access to entity - lock upon reading
2. Synchrionize method execution
3. Serialize transaction
4. **Use version controll mechanism**

Comment: Does this also apply to firestore (firebase)? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions